# google_maps_flutter, Getting the center coordinate from the different padding

Tags: flutter, google-maps

How to get the center coordinate of a Google Map that the padding values of top and bottom are 0.0 (no bottom padding) from a coordinate (for example LatLng(37.7749, -122.4194)) and the padding is set to top 50.0 and bottom 200.0 ?

So far what i am doing is

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MapSample(),
    );
  }
}

class MapSample extends StatefulWidget {
  const MapSample({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MapSample> createState() => MapSampleState();
}

class MapSampleState extends State<MapSample> {
  bool _desirePadding = true;
  late GoogleMapController _mapController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    LatLng myCoordinate = const LatLng(37.7749, -122.4194); // Center coordinate
    double desiredTopPadding = 50.0; // Desired top padding value in pixels
    double desiredBottomPadding =
        200.0; // Desired bottom padding value in pixels

    // Calculate the my lower coordinate
    double topPaddingInDegrees = (desiredTopPadding /
        (156543.03392 * cos(myCoordinate.latitude * pi / 180.0)));
    double bottomPaddingInDegrees = (desiredBottomPadding /
        (156543.03392 * cos(myCoordinate.latitude * pi / 180.0)));

    double myLowerCoordinateLatitude =
        myCoordinate.latitude - (bottomPaddingInDegrees - topPaddingInDegrees);

    debugPrint("MY LOWER COORDINATE $myLowerCoordinateLatitude");

    return Scaffold(
      body: GoogleMap(
        initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
          target: myCoordinate,
          zoom: 17.0,
        ),
        padding: _desirePadding == true
            ? EdgeInsets.only(
                top: desiredTopPadding, bottom: desiredBottomPadding)
            : const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0, bottom: 0),
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) async {
          _mapController = controller;
          await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1000));
          _mapController
              .animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(CameraPosition(
            target: myCoordinate,
            zoom: 17.0,
          )));
        },
        markers: {
          Marker(
            infoWindow: const InfoWindow(title: "My Coordinate"),
            markerId: const MarkerId('myMaker'),
            position: myCoordinate,
          ),
          Marker(
            infoWindow: const InfoWindow(title: "My Lower Coordinate"),
            markerId: const MarkerId('lowerMarker'),
            position: LatLng(myLowerCoordinateLatitude, myCoordinate.longitude),
          ),
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: Wrap(
        direction: Axis.vertical,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: FloatingActionButton.extended(
              onPressed: () async {
                final c = CameraPosition(
                    target: _desirePadding
                        ? myCoordinate
                        : LatLng(
                            myLowerCoordinateLatitude, myCoordinate.longitude),
                    zoom: 17.0);

                _mapController.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(c));
              },
              label: _desirePadding
                  ? const Text('To My Coordinate')
                  : const Text('To My Lower Coordinate'),
              icon: const Icon(Icons.directions_boat),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: FloatingActionButton.extended(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _desirePadding = !_desirePadding;
                  });
                },
                backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
                label: _desirePadding
                    ? const Text('Set Padding To Bottom: 0, Top: 0')
                    : Text(
                        'Set Padding To Bottom: $desiredBottomPadding, Top: $desiredTopPadding'),
                icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
              )),

          // Add more buttons here
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

but this approach is not very accurate

[Map image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojlAs.jpg)

[Map Image Update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2CQy.jpg)

Comment: So you want the marker to be set in the center always?

Comment: The value 156543.03392 is a constant used in the calculations to convert between screen pixels and angular distance on the Earth's surface (specifically, in terms of latitude degrees). This conversion factor is often used in mapping and geospatial calculations.

Comment: @Ankit Gada https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojlAs.jpg

Comment: and `topPaddingInDegrees` / `bottomPaddingInDegrees` are computed correctly? how come?

Comment: @pskink I got this reference from ChatGPT, and the results are close to accurate. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojlAs.jpg

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to calculate the lower coordinate based on the desired top and bottom padding while keeping the **center coordinate constant**. Your approach is mostly correct, but there's a slight issue in your calculation of the **lower coordinate latitude**. You need to add the **padding degrees** to the **center latitude** instead of **subtracting** them.

```
    LatLng centerCoordinate = LatLng(37.7749, -122.4194); // Center coordinate

    double desiredTopPadding = 50.0; // Desired top padding value in pixels

    double desiredBottomPadding = 200.0; // Desired bottom padding value in pixels

    // Calculate the padding in latitude degrees
    double topPaddingInDegrees = (desiredTopPadding / (156543.03392 * cos(centerCoordinate.latitude * pi / 180.0)));
    double bottomPaddingInDegrees = (desiredBottomPadding / (156543.03392 * cos(centerCoordinate.latitude * pi / 180.0)));

    // Calculate the lower coordinate
    double lowerLatitude = centerCoordinate.latitude + bottomPaddingInDegrees;
```

may be these calculations may help you out.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not the answer I was expecting. You are right, I want to calculate the coordinates of my lower position. imagine where you are in the middle of the coordinates with the padding values ​​in this case bottom: 200.0 , top: 50.0, then you want to calculate the center of the coordinates below you with the padding values ​​in this case bottom: 0.0 , top: 0,0. I have updated the sample code above, maybe you want to try it.

Comment: If you try the code above https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2CQy.jpg , after pressing the "set padding To ..." button, then pressing the "To My ..." button
if the screen remains still, it means that the lower coordinates are correct, but conversely, if the screen is still moving up or down, it means that the lower coordinates are still wrong.